# css3 animation timing differs between firefox and other browsers

Tags: css

I have a couple of square divs that I am rotating from 0 to 90 degrees, then back to 0. Within each square are 2 images, absolutely positioned on top of each other.

Visibility between the images toggles, but you should not see the toggle. It should occur when the square is turned at 90 degrees (perpendicular to the screen) and therefor not visible.

**My problem: the timing is perfect in firefox, but off in chrome, safari, and IE. I can't figure out why.**

I am using css3 animation and keyframes to control the rotation of the square container divs, and also to change the visibility of the images by toggling the z-index of the "hidden" image.

**One note**: I am using PHP to get a random number, then inserting that as an inline style for the animation-delay value. I originally did this with jquery .css(), but I was attempting to minimize the work on the front end, since that seems to be where to timing problem is.

Here is the code:

```css
.pair-container { 
 -webkit-animation-name: rotate;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 8s;
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 
 animation-name: rotate;
 animation-duration: 8s;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
     
 display:inline-block;
 height:150px;
 margin:5px; 
 position:relative;
 width:150px;
}
.pair-container a {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
 z-index:0;
}
.pair-container a:first-child {
 -webkit-animation-name: flip; 
 -webkit-animation-delay: 2s; 
 -webkit-animation-duration: 8s;   
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;  
 
 animation-name: flip; 
 animation-delay: 2s; 
 animation-duration: 8s;   
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;   
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
    transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
    transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }  
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
}
@keyframes flip {
 0% { 
   z-index: 0; 
 }
 25% {
  z-index: 1; 
 }
 50% { 
   z-index: 1; 
 }
 75% {
  z-index: 1; 
 }
 100% { 
   z-index: 0; 
 }
  
}
```

```html
<div style="animation-delay:2s;" class="pair-container">
  <a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com" style="animation-delay:2s;">
    <img src="http://s24.postimg.org/5o8rk8i8x/fire_drink.jpg">
  </a>
  <a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com">
    <img src="http://s27.postimg.org/g1bk23lyn/food.jpg">
  </a>
</div>

<div style="animation-delay:3s;" class="pair-container">
  <a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com" style="animation-delay:3s;">
    <img src="http://s27.postimg.org/g1bk23lyn/food.jpg">
  </a>
  <a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com">
    <img src="http://s24.postimg.org/5o8rk8i8x/fire_drink.jpg">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code

```
    0% { 
        z-index: 0; 
    }
    25% {
        z-index: 1; 
    }
```

is the problem. You need that the change of the z-index occurs precisely at 25%, but this code doesn't warrant it. In Chrome, it's happening at 12.5%.

The correct code to make this happen is:

```
    0%, 24.99% { 
        z-index: 0; 
    }
    25% {
        z-index: 1; 
    }
```

### corrected snippet

```css
.pair-container { 
 -webkit-animation-name: rotate;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 8s;
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 
 animation-name: rotate;
 animation-duration: 8s;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
     
 display:inline-block;
 height:150px;
 margin:5px; 
 position:relative;
 width:150px;
}
.pair-container a {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
 z-index:0;
}
.pair-container a:first-child {
 -webkit-animation-name: flip; 
 -webkit-animation-delay: 2s; 
 -webkit-animation-duration: 8s;   
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;  
 
 animation-name: flip; 
 animation-delay: 2s; 
 animation-duration: 8s;   
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;   
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
    transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
    transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }  
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
}
@keyframes flip {
 0%, 24.99% { 
   z-index: 0; 
 }
 25% {
  z-index: 1; 
 }
 50% { 
   z-index: 1; 
 }
 75% {
  z-index: 1; 
 }
 75.01%, 100% { 
   z-index: 0; 
 }
  
}
```

```html
<div style="animation-delay:2s;" class="pair-container">
  <a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com" style="animation-delay:2s;">
    <img src="http://s24.postimg.org/5o8rk8i8x/fire_drink.jpg">
  </a>
  <a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com">
    <img src="http://s27.postimg.org/g1bk23lyn/food.jpg">
  </a>
</div>

<div style="animation-delay:3s;" class="pair-container">
  <a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com" style="animation-delay:3s;">
    <img src="http://s27.postimg.org/g1bk23lyn/food.jpg">
  </a>
  <a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com">
    <img src="http://s24.postimg.org/5o8rk8i8x/fire_drink.jpg">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Happy that it helped !